# How to create a dynamic HTML link that grabs the token ID from the current session?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is that even possible?

As an example, the Main Menu page in this site is:

https://my.domain.com/WEPROD/WebProcess?TOKENIDX=5647385647&type=M&constituency=WBST&pid=MAIN-WBST

and a page:

https://my.domain.com/WEPROD/WebProcess?TOKENIDX=5647385647&SS=1&APP=ST&CONSTITUENCY=WBST

5647385647&SS is my token.  It won't work for other users. So the link would need to somehow capture the token id portion dynamically from the current session or else users would be asked to log in again

btw- I can't just omit the token or I would mess things up later

Comment: Are you using any server-side code? Or do you need to do this using only JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the querystring with `location.search` So the following would give you a map of all key-value pairs in the querystring, from which you can extract the token:

```
const queryArgs = new Map(
  location.search
    .substring(1) //get rid of the '?' at the start
    .split('&') //split into key-value pairs
    .map(pair => pair.split('=')) //make each key-value pair into [key, value]
)
console.log(queryArgs.get('TOKENIDX')) //'5647385647'
```

Comment: and after extraction, how do I reference it in the link?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can't you just concatenate the pieces of the new URL together with the token you've extracted?

Comment: what would the dynamic (concatenated link) look like?  Would it reference variables instead of actual values?